# Disabling discrete graphics before/during installation?

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, amd-graphics, macbook-pro

I have a MacBook Pro which has a dead AMD 6770m discrete chip. Every time it gets triggered the laptop will lockup and/or crash.

Is there a way to install Ubuntu (Mate) so that the discrete chip doesn't get recognized/ never gets triggered?

The only solution I've seen so far is to type some commands in to Terminal, but I need the chip to be deactivated during installation already/ never get installed in the first place.

And another side question I have is, how deactivated will the chip be? I currently have managed to "disable" the chip in macOS but although it isn't getting triggered, it is still constantly drawing max power generating a lot of heat and causing the battery to drain extremely quickly.

Comment: What is the version of the MacBook Pro? May be you can edit the boot loader on the liveusb (if you use liveusb to install). But the standard boot loader can't switch between the gpus. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics and https://github.com/0xbb/gpu-switch/issues/27 and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MacBookPro11,x about switcheroo. Is there a text mode installation for Ubuntu?

Comment: It's a late 2011 (8,3) 17" MBP. And I'm not sure about there being a text mode installation for Ubuntu (Mate). I'm totally new to Linux and am just curious if it'll be a good alternative solution for bringing my MB back to life.